# Rails nested models and child validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models.

Exemplary:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages, allow_destroy: true
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book

  validate_on_create :count_within_bounds

  LIMIT = 200

  private

  def count_within_bounds
    if self.book.pages.count >= LIMIT
      errors.add_to_base("Number of pages cannot be greater than #{LIMIT}")
    end
  end
end
```

Now when update the book through a nested form everything is working just fine. I can edit let's say the title and add new pages. But if the page validation fails the other changes made to the book model are not getting saved either.

I understand that it's all being saved in one transaction but is there a way to persist the parent regardless without having to do it manually in two steps, i.e. saving the parent first without pages_attributes?

Comment: What's the work flow look like?  I mean, do you want to save the Book but still show an error?  Rails out of the box isn't meant to handle a situation like this.

Comment: Exactly this. What I want is to persist all changes made to the Book and just skip invalid children.

Comment: There's no great way to handle it in Rails.  You have to skip the validation and then only save those pages that are less than the limit.  It's a bit of a nasty situation, though, and you need to alert the user that although the operation succeeded it didn't save all the data. Again, no easy way to do that with Rails.  I would seriously consider a different work flow so that the user doesn't believe something succeeded when it really didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can take away the validation and do something like:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %> 
    # book attribute stuff....

      <% if @book.pages.count < 200 %>
            <%= f.fields_for :pages, @book.pages.create do |ff| %>
            <%= ff.text_field :attribute %><br>
           <% end %>
         <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Now only books with less than 200 pages will get a form that includes fields to add pages.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you want to save the parent only and skip the validations for your `Page` subclass you can use the [`validate`](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) option in your `Book` model.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, validate: false, dependent: :destroy
end
```